# Accessing WebService Running in AWS instance using Instance id

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-ssm

We have an AWS instance in which a webservice is running in a particular port, which can handle requests and send response back, Now **we have to send request
to that webservice using the AWS Instance Id, Not by using the Instance's Ipaddress.**

Need to support this in windows and Linux environments

Is there any way to achieve this ? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Using SSM Run command? Its not clear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: But we need to post requests.Is it possible with SSM?

Comment: Yes, but they would go from localhost. Same as you would ssh into an instance and curl the service from there. But anyway, its still not clear do you mean by "AWS Instance Id, Not by using the Instance's Ipaddress"? Use DNS name, if you don't want to use ip address?

Comment: @Marcin you are saying like AWS-RunRemotescript

Comment: Yes. This executes a script on your instance. The script could call the webservice from the inside of the instance. But if this is a "webservice" why it can't be called as any other web service?

Comment: @Marcin Usually we send request to our webservice with IP address and Port.I am asking like is there any possible to communicate with the webservice using instance id and port

Comment: I'm not aware of such a possibility. You can use DNS, but then this will resolve to IP anyway.